# wget install ubuntu

Tags: wget

I only have ssh access to this server that is running a Ubuntu 20.4, however our app is not compatible and I need to downgrade or reinstall 18.04 LTS. Can someone give me instruction on how I can do this from the shell using wget or curl?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use wget or curl to install Ubuntu. You need to run the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Please think twice: Is there some other way for you to access the computer, or to ask somebody with physical access to reinstall 18.04 LTS, or maybe arrange something like KVM access?

Comment: How is your "app" "not compatible"? It may be that downgrading is unnecessary.

Comment: ok I will figure it out. I am in CA and they are in another state, we have a custom app and it is not working and I spoke to our developers and I will need 18.04. Its okay I can wait for a tech to get on site and then I will use TeamViewer to connect. Thanks anyway I was just checking to see if there was a way to install it using those.